# C: function that checks if a matrix is a submatrix of another

Tags: c, matrix

Given two matrices I want to check if one is contained in the other, i have the dimension of the matrices, and i have written a function which doesn't work and i don't know why: here is the code explained:

```
               /*Where m,n are the dimensions of the first matrix 
                and u,v the dimensions of the second one, the integer
                 pointers are to remember from where,row and column,
                 (for the first time) the matrices overlap */        


            int function(int a[][SIZE],int m,int n, int  b[][SIZE],int u,int v, int *r,int *c)
                    {
                     int i,j,x,y,cont=0;

        /*The first two 'for' cycles are to choose a suitable starting point for the confrontation  */ 
                     for(i=0;i<m-u+1;i++)        
                     {
                         for(j=0;j<n-v+1;j++)
                         {
                             cont=0; /*Every time it choose the starting point, the counter start from 0 */
                                 for(x=0;x<u;x++)
                                 {
                                     for(y=0;y<v;y++)
                                     {
                                         if(a[i+x][j+y] == b[x][y]) /*Here there is the confrontation between the elements*/
                                         {
                                             cont++; /*This counts the number of equal elements between the second matrix b and the (same-dimension-part of) first matrix*/


                                         }

                                     } 
                                 }      /*It does the confrontations as many times as the elements of b, so u*v times */

                                if(cont==u * v) /*If the elements are equal for every element of b, the program return 1*/
                                 {
                                     *r=i;
                                     *c=j;
                                     return 1;


                                 }

                         }
                     }

                   /*If it has never returned one, it return 0*/
                     return 0;
                    }
```

Here there is an example of usage of the function:

```
int function(int a[][SIZE],int m,int n, int  b[][SIZE],int u,int v, int *r,int *c);

        int main()
        {
         int i,j,x=0,y=0;
         int a[10][10],b[2][2];
         int *r=&x,*c=&y;

        srand(time(NULL));

        for(i=0;i<10;i++)
         {
         for(j=0;j<10;j++)
        {
             if(i<2 && j<2)
                 b[i][j]=rand()%2;

         a[i][j]=rand()%2;
        }
        }
        i=function(a,10,10,b,2,2,r,c);
        if(i==1)
             printf("(%d , %d)\n", *r,*c);
        else
             printf("b is not a submatrix of a\n");

        return 0;
        }
```

P.s. I tried to print, for every time `a[i+x][j+y]==b[x][y]`, the elements `a[i+x][j+y]` and `b[x][y]`. But it happens that b[x][y] is, sometime, the wrong value (e.g. if b is made of ones only, it happens that after a confrontation b[x][y] is printed as zero).

Comment: Look ok to me. The only question is: how did the higher level code call the function? See [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: @user3386109 I edited my question with some more details

Comment: The function declaration says that both `a` and `b` have `SIZE` columns. There are two problems with that. 1) You haven't shown the definition of `SIZE` (which means you didn't read about [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)). 2) The arrays in `main` don't have the same number of columns.